# acts_as_votable: have two voting types for the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I have implemented a voting system with acts_as_votable gem on Ruby on Rails, for liking posts (upvote/downvote). Now I want to create another voting type for posts too. Like accept answer/ dont accept answer. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is, indeed, possible.

Albeit, you might lose some of the helper methods.

Acts As Votable allows you to work with scopes.  So you can easily say

```
current_user.likes @post, voter_scope: "endorsement"
```

and you can check all the votes for an endorsement with

```
@post.find_votes_for vote_scope: "endorsement"
```

And the same for an accepted answer

```
current_user.likes @post, voter_scope: "acceptance"
@post.find_votes_for vote_scope: "acceptance"
```

-- Be careful of using scopes withe words like 'like' and 'dislike' and 'vote' -- as those are method names in some uses of this gems and could get very confusing.

So even though the documentation says you can only have one vote per voter model, what it really means is that you can only have one SCOPED vote per model.

Comment: i tried with vote_scope but now the vote count it's not couting well. i did it like this:  `performance_indicator.improvement_actions.sum(:cached_votes_total, vote_scope: 'upvote')` and also I cant order by vote now

Comment: I wouldn't use the word upvote for your scope.  I wouldn't use of the terms that  the gem uses as methods. -- and additionally, I'm not surprised you can't order by vote, as also mentioned you might lose some funcitonality.   this isn't the way the gem in designed, or any of the voting gems really